# Delete multiple data from db with checkbox

Tags: php, database, sql-delete

How to delete multiple data from table with checkbox?
I have this code:

```
<form id="prefForm" action="coments-del.php" method="post">

<?

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");      
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM data WHERE id=$myrow[post]");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    printf ("
         <tr>
           <td>
                <input type='checkbox' name='id' value='%s'  />
                </td>        
                <td>%s</td>
           <td>%s</td>
                <td>%s</td>
         ",$myrow["id"],$myrow["id"],$myrow["author"],$myrow["text"]);
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>

<input name="submit-button" type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Here is the coments-del.php where you get brought after submiting form in script above.

In the head is:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) { $id = $_POST['id']; }
```

At the body is the code that proccess the deleting.

```
<?php 
if (isset($id)) {
    $result = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='$id'");

    if ($result == 'true') {echo "Comment Deleted!";}
    else {echo "Error: Nothing was deleted!";}

} else {
    echo "Unknown Error! Contact Administrator.";
}

?>
```

Comment: here is the obligatory "you should use [PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql_* functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to make your checkbox name an array.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='%s'  />
```

And when your script receive the post, parse that array out to the appropriate sql clause.

```
$clause="";
if (isset($_POST['id'])) { 
   foreach ($_POST['id'] as $p)
   $clause.="id='$p' OR"; 
}
$clause=substr($clause,0,-2);
```

Finally put the clause into the query in the where clause.

Comment: so i have to put your php code in the code after submiting? 
This one - coments-del.php ?

Comment: first part in the html form creating the post, and second part in the comments-del.php.

Comment: but it doesnt work. I pasted last part in comments-del.php and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you but I usually save PKs into an array and then do something like this:

```
<?php
//... process your ids (eg. filter out not numerical values) and save into an array

if(count($ids_array)>0){
   mysql_query('DELETE FROM comments WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $ids_array).')');
}
?>
```